# Why does class String constructor method with parameter StringBuffer use synchronize block while the constructor with StringBuilder doesn't?

Tags: java, string

Why does class String constructor method with parameter StringBuffer use synchronize block while the constructor with StringBuilder doesn't?

```
public String(StringBuffer buffer) {
    synchronized(buffer) {
        this.value = Arrays.copyOf(buffer.getValue(), buffer.length());
    }
}

public String(StringBuilder builder) {
    this.value = Arrays.copyOf(builder.getValue(), builder.length());
}
```

Comment: because `StringBuffer` is intended to be used in multi-threaded environment (most of its methods are synchronized); `StringBuilder` is meant for single-threaded use, not synchronized

Comment: Which version of Java is this? In the most recent version, the constructors have changed.

Comment: This is explained in the [Javadoc of `StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html): _"This class provides an API compatible with StringBuffer, but with no guarantee of synchronization"_. This is the whole reason `StringBuilder` even exists.

Comment: This one is JDK8, it has changed in high versions.     public String(StringBuffer buffer) {
        this(buffer.toString());
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringBuffer` is designed to be thread-safe and used in multithread applications.

But even with that design it still would be possible that **between invoking** `buffer.getValue()` and `buffer.length()` some other thread could attempt to modify `buffer`. This means that `getValue()` would reflect state before that modification but `length()` state after that modification.

Synchronizing both calls on buffer object via `synchronized(buffer)` inside String constructor prevents other threads from accessing synchronized methods of that `buffer`. This especially includes methods able to modify `buffer`, so it would be impossible to do so in the middle of processing it by String constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Because the difference of `StringBuilder` versus `StringBuffer` is that `StringBuffer` is thread-safe while `StringBuilder` is not. Note that thread-safety comes with performance penalty, so `StringBuffer` should only be used in multi thread usage.

From the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html):

> String buffers are safe for use by multiple threads. The methods are
>   synchronized where necessary so that all the operations on any
>   particular instance behave as if they occur in some serial order that
>   is consistent with the order of the method calls made by each of the
>   individual threads involved.